# Flexbox paddings (occupy more than 100% width)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm working with @c4rlosls, we have 2 issues: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44WcI.jpg
If `container-fluid` father has `px-0`, it occupies more than 100% width.
And `.cont2 a`  and `.cont3 a` haven't got 100% width of their father's div.

How can I fix these 2 issues?

```css
.inew1{
 background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 100%; 
}
.inew2{
 background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 100%; 
}
.inew3{
 background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-fluid px-0 "> 
      <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class=" col-xl-8 col-lg-12 inew1 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
           

           
           <a href="google.uno" class="w-100">
              <h1 class="">Title</h1>
              <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          


        <div class="container-fluid col-xl-4 col-lg-12 ">
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xl-12 inew2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
            <div class="row">
           <a href="google.uno" class="w-100">
              <h1 class="">Title2</h1>
              <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-12 inew3 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">
            <div class="row">
           <a href="google.uno">
              <h1 class="">Title3</h1>
              <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
            </a>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your ALL code. because the problem is unclear.

Comment: Don't nest containers. Read the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) and understand how the grid is used. A col shouldn't also be a container-fluid. The `row` is *only* used to contain `col*`.

Comment: Your shared code snippet doesn't occupy more than 100% of the width so I don't understand the question ? I see you have a `container-fluid` inside another `container-fluid` but it is a full width container so you can use `w-100` for the child.

Comment: @DogukanCavus Code updated, is enought now?

Comment: @Zim if i remove `container-fluid` from `container-fluid col-xl-4 col-lg-12` i have the same error, father `<div class="container-fluid px-0 ">` ocuppy more than 100%

Comment: Because you have more nested rows that aren't using `no-gutters`. Take the inner container-fluid off.

Answer (score 0):

i made a template for you. you can use this.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
.col1 {
  flex:3;
  height:500px;
}
.col2 {
  flex:2;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:500px;
}

.bg {
  background:url("https://picsum.photos/800/600");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.bg2 {
  background:url("https://picsum.photos/600/800");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  flex:1;
  position:relative;
}

.bg3 {
  background:url("https://picsum.photos/500/400");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  flex:1;
  position:relative;
}

.text_area {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:70px;
  padding:20px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  justify-content:center;
}

.text_area .title {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:28px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.text_area .description {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:728px){
  .flex {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  .col1 {
    height:250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="bg">
      <div class="text_area"><div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col2">
    <div class="bg2">
      <div class="text_area"><div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="bg3">
      <div class="text_area"><div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ty, but i need use bootstrap grid system (responsive `text_area`) :/

Comment: anymore responsive. again look.

Answer (score 0):

In this you have to do below changes in your code to solve issue.

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0 "> 
  <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class=" col-xl-8 col-lg-12 inew1 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">



        <a href="google.uno" class="w-100">
          <h1 class="">Title</h1>
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </a>
      </div>



    <div class="container-fluid col-xl-4 col-lg-12 ">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class=" col-xl-12 inew2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">

        <a href="google.uno" class="w-100">
          <h1 class="">Title2</h1>
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xl-12 inew3 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-start flex-column">

        <a href="google.uno" class="w-100">
          <h1 class="">Title3</h1>
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In above code i have added "no-gutters" in row after col-xl-4 which solve scrollbar problem... 
And i have remove `<div class=row>` from 2nd column(inew2,inew3) which solve your title background issue..

Comment: Ty, but i still having scroll, if i remove `px-0` it fix, but i still having a padding: imgur.com/a/NZKs0KE